# Lightning Component that frames Experience Cloud Site on the Lightning Record Page. Requires login

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, salesforcedx, experience-cloud, experience-builder-page

I need to place an Experience Cloud Site on the record page. For that I use Lightning Component with Iframe.

User must have access to the site page specified in 'src' attribute for Iframe(for exp. src="https://my-site.sandbox.my.site.com/mySite/home"). But instead user sees site's login page ("https://my-site.sandbox.my.site.com/mySite/login") and is required to log in. Is it possible to setup login process 'under the hood' so the user doesn't need to log in manually? (Public access to site is not allowed)

My assumption is that I need to generate an access token for the Experience Cloud Site and store it in Cookies, but I'm afraid it's not secure or even possible within Salesforce.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve? Please edit your question and provide more context, do not reply in comments.